Accessing datadog from ecs ec2 docker container
I have a spring boot service running in ECS using EC2 (not fargate).  In the spring boot's application properties, I specify the datadog api key, and it works locally sending the metrics to DD, but there's no APM.
In my ECS cluster, we use ECS with EC2 not fargate. I have Datadog agent running as daemon service as mentioned here. The APM part is working as expected.
But:

from the docker container, I couldn't access api.datadogdq.com. But in the EC2 instance, I'm able to access to api.datadogdq.com. I'm using awsvpc network, is that because of that I can't access the datadog api directly?
I was thinking of connecting to the Datadog Agent on the instance for custom metrics. But the port 8125 seems to not be on. I couldn't curl to it or do anything. Love some suggestions here.
What's the best practice here? Since for APM and custom metrics, they are two different endpoints. Do people usually use both together?

Thank you!
